# Lucene indexing slow in docker

Tags: docker, lucene

I am running Lucene 3.4 and it is indexing around 8GB of data. When lucene is running from a docker container it's showing degraded performance - takes more than twice the time(~50 mins) than outside of docker (~20 mins). Looking at the thread dumps - it looks like DocumentsWriterPerThreadPool is getting locked by some thread very frequently. Anyone has any suggestion?

I tried increasing the buffer memory, lowering/increasing number of threads processing as well. But it's not helping.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.